# MicroSD: Cracked and punctured

Tags: memory

I have a punctured microsd card... basically with a nail/screwdriver puncture in the center of the card. Can ANYTHING be done to pull information from the card?

Is it a lost cause?! Thank you.

Comment: I assume you tried to read the card and can't?  Depending on what was damaged, a portion might still be readable.  If not, the only thing I found after extensive research involved leaving goat entrails under a full moon and chanting.  I'd be surprised if that actually works, though.

Comment: Ah yes, the goat entrails methodology. Never fails!

Comment: @nanananad can you post a picture of the damage, I am intensely curious as to *how* it occurred...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, no.

That said, there *are* companies that will be able to tear the card down to interrogate the memory itself. This very much depends on the extent of the physical damage, and whether the memory itself is damaged.

[image]

<sub>Image courtesy of [StorageReview](http://www.storagereview.com/sandisk_ultra_microsdxc_128gb_card_review)</sub>

Bear in mind that different cards may have the physical location in a different place.

Specialist recovery however would likely be incredibly expensive and from what you've said I'd presume the memory is actually damaged, so unless the card contains some absolutely irreplaceable data, I would say to cut your losses.

Going forwards, always remember to keep backups.

Comment: What, you're ruling out the goat entrails and chanting thing?

Comment: @fixer1234 I figured he'd have already tried that, first logical step to take, surely?

Comment: Does the card have to be cracked all the way through for it to be absolutely FUBAR, or is a good puncture right into the middle enough to render it to the same state?

Comment: @nanananad See the picture attached, the black rectangle holds the actual data. If that is in any way damaged, assume it's FUBAR. Honestly, they're extremely fragile, I'd be surprised if it was able to withstand much damage at all.

Comment: @Jonno Thank you for the speedy reply... so, is the layout similar with a microSD (or does that turn into 'any part of the microSD, since its much smaller')?

Comment: @nanananad That's a cross section *of* a microSD (beneath the plastic shell). As stated, yours may vary, but they're all of a similar layout.

Comment: @Jonno I understand there are oxide trenches that (hold?) charges (or impede them), so I'm assuming if any part of that assembly/array is broken it would render the thing fairly dead, if not completely, no? At that point (ultra costly) reconstruction would probably be even out of the question...?